# While loop will not exit once False, and random number generator is outputting the same number each time

Tags: c#, do-while

I have a basic do while loop that will not exit once it is changed to false. I've stepped through debugging and it does in fact get returned as false. Yet the loop continues to run.

Secondly, at the end of my last if/else statement I have it where selectednumber should return a new random number and start the game over. But it just returns the same number from the the program was originally ran. What am I doing wrong there?

main class:

```
class HighLowApp
  {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        Admin startup = new Admin();
        startup.ConsoleSetup();

        startup.Instructions();

        Control startGame = new Control();
        startGame.LetsPlay();


    }
}

  namespace mellon_HighLow
  {
     class Control
    {
     public static int selectedNumber = 0;
     public static Random num = new Random();
     public static bool playAgain = true;


     public Control()
     { }

     public void LetsPlay()
     {
        //variables
        int userGuess;
        selectedNumber = num.Next(1, 501);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 500.");
            userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            UI output = new UI();
            output.CompareNumbers(userGuess, selectedNumber, playAgain);

        } while (playAgain == true);
    }
  }
 }
```

NEXT CLASS::

```
  class UI
      {
       public static Random num = new Random();
       public static int keepGoing;
       public static int numGuesses;

       public UI()
       { }

        public void CompareNumbers(int userGuess, int selectedNumber, bool playAgain)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(selectedNumber);
                if (userGuess > selectedNumber)
                {
                    Console.Beep(600, 300);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nToo High! Guess Again!");
                    numGuesses++;

                }

                else if (userGuess < selectedNumber)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(300, 300);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nToo Low! Guess Again!");
                        numGuesses++;

                }
                else
                {
                        Console.Beep(350, 300);
                        Console.Beep(380, 200);
                        Console.Beep(380, 100);
                        Console.Beep(500, 1100);
                        numGuesses++;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nCongrats! It took you " + numGuesses + " guesses to win.");
                        numGuesses = 0;
                        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to play again or 2 to quit.");
                        keepGoing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                        while (keepGoing != 1 && keepGoing != 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPlease type either 1 or 2 only!");
                            keepGoing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }

                            if (keepGoing == 2)
                               playAgain = false;

                            else
                            {
                                Console.Clear();
                                selectedNumber = num.Next(1, 5001);
                            }

                }

        }



}
```

}

Comment: Please post complete code

Comment: You can't change the value type parameters `int` or `bool` if the method parameters are not `ref`.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno that is all of the code

Comment: Nope, code is missing, copy paste everything.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno sorry. you're right. updating now.

Comment: perhaps I missed an edit but idk why this was downvoted, even though it's a basic mistake, it's a much better attempt that alot on here

Comment: @MichaelM , try to delete all the code in your post, go to visual studio press CTRL + A, then copy, then paste here

Comment: @MarcoSalerno that is ALL of the code aside from the namespace in the second class. If you're referring to the using directives (is that what they are called) then those are straight out of what VS provides. I didn't change or add any.

Comment: @MichaelM no static main?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno hahah you got me. Forgot about the most important one. Though to be fair, its not doing a whole lot.   :)

Comment: I wanted to solve your problem but i feel like you are posting a different code, so i can't help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change value type parameters like `bool` if the method parameter is not `ref`.

So you could use this(note `ref` before the bool and int parameters):

```
public void CompareNumbers(int userGuess, ref int selectedNumber, ref bool playAgain)
{...}
```

...

```
output.CompareNumbers(userGuess, ref selectedNumber, ref playAgain);
```

But easier would be to just `return false` from the method when you want to stop.

```
if (keepGoing == 2)
     return false;
else
{
    Console.Clear();
    selectedNumber = num.Next(1, 5001);
}
```

Of course you have to change `void` to `bool`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that worked! Any idea on the number generator?

Comment: @MichaelM the selectedNumber parameter in your compare numbers method would also have to be `ref`

Comment: @MichaelM: David is right, i have edited my answer. You are modifying the int-parameter in the method.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the playAgain boolean variable. In C# booleans are passed by value. The argument variable named playAgain in your CompareNumbers method has a local scope so when you change it, this does not affect the variable (which happens to have the same name) called playAgain in your main class.

You have a choice of approaches:

Either make the CompareNumbers return a boolean and use that as you used playAgain.

OR:

Use the ref keyword in your method parameter like so:

```
public void CompareNumbers(int userGuess, int selectedNumber, ref bool playAgain)
```

In this case your code will work as you were expecting.

In terms of the Random numbers. You are creating a new Random object in every loop of the code. This uses the same seed and generates the same number. You should avoid recreating the object but just call .Next every time you want a new number.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method CompareNumbers and pass the arguments selectedNumber, playAgain. Since those Arguments are not passed by reference those arguments are only changed inside the CompareNumbers method and NOT in the calling method.

It is important to understand that the variables passed are different variables than the one you have in the calling method!

You could try something like this but note that this is not good codestyle in my opinion:

```
public void CompareNumbers(int userGuess, ref int selectedNumber, ref bool playAgain)
```

You should rethink why you are using the Method CompareNumbers!